# Timer inside function

Tags: python, sorting, time

EDIT: I'm in need of a timer that counts how long it takes to solve an unordered list after the user enters it.

I cant seem to get the time_selection_sort function running. I want the timer to begin as soon as the user has inputted a list.

```
from time import perf_counter
def swap(lst, i, j):
tmp = lst[i]
lst[i] = lst[j]
lst[j] = tmp

def swap_if_greater(lst, i, j):
if lst[i] > lst[j]:
    tmp = lst[i]
    lst[i] = lst[j]
    lst[j] = tmp

def find_index_of_min(lst):
min_index = 0
min_value = lst[0]
for i, value in enumerate(lst):
    if value < min_value:
        min_index = i
        min_value = value
return min_index
def selection_sort_out_of_place(input_list):
    # make a copy so we don't destroy the original data
    input_list = list(input_list)
    output_list = []
    # sort values into output_list, one at a time
    while input_list:
        print('Input list:', repr(input_list))
        print('Output list:', repr(output_list))
        min_index = find_index_of_min(input_list)
        value = input_list.pop(min_index)
        print('Sorting the value', repr(value))
        output_list.append(value)

    return output_list

def time_selection_sort(input_list):
    # generate random list
    lst = selection_sort_out_of_place(input_list)
    # measure running time
    start_time = perf_counter()
    insertion_sort(lst)
    end_time = perf_counter()

    # return time in milliseconds
    return 1000 * (end_time - start_time)

t = time_selection_sort(100)
print('Time:', t, 'ms')
```

Comment: Shouldn't the input to time_selection_sort be a list? Also, find_index_of_min is not defined here.

Comment: Please include the specific error you're running into. If you have further errors after resolving that then you may need to ask new questions.